# How to draw an image from a 2d array in modern openGL

Tags: c++, image, opengl, draw, opengl-compat

I want to draw points with openGL, I have a 32x32 screen size and I want to fill it with the color red, however I don't understand how the parameters of `glVertex2f(-1, 0.5)` are working

My first instinct was to do something like this:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);                 // Initialize GLUT
glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Setup Test"); // Create a window with the given title
glutInitWindowSize(32, 32);   // Set the window's initial width & height
glutDisplayFunc(displaySpectrogram); // Register display callback handler for window re-paint
glutMainLoop();           // Enter the event-processing loop

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color to black and opaque
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);         // Clear the color buffer (background)

glBegin(GL_POINTS);              
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
    {
        glVertex2f(i,j);
    }
}
glEnd();

glFlush();  // Render now
```

But `glVertex2f()` parameters range is -1 to 1 I think so I'm not sure how to achieve that.

There is another way with texture but I have no idea on how to use them and there are no tutorials for that online

Comment: Any reason you use legacy OpenGl? If you don't have a string reason to stick to outdated technology I suggest to forget this and learn OpenGl3.x or newer. There are plenty of good tutorials out there.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about it a lot, I installed it from an old tutorial which had that version, I should upgrade yea

Comment: can you link me a good tutorial? I just upgraded to OpenGl3, how can I implement what I've asked? @churill

Comment: *"I have a 32x32 screen size and I want to fill it with the color "* - so why do you not draw a quad? Why do you not use [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml)/[Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) (regardless of points or quads)?

Comment: because that's just a simple example, my project requires me to draw each pixel with different color @Rabbid76

Comment: @yarinCohen So why do you not use a texture? Why do you not use `glOrtho`?

Comment: [Learn OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/) is an excellent resource .  [TheCherno](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2) if you prefer Videos

Comment: because I don't know how, a simple example like what I said would be wonderful @Rabbid76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use an [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection). In Orthographic Projection, the view space coordinates are linearly mapped to the clip space coordinates and normalized device coordinates. The viewing volume is defined by 6 distances (left, right, bottom, top, near, far). The values for left, right, bottom, top, near and far define a cuboid (box).
With legacy OpenGL matrices you can use [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xm) to set an orthographic projection matrix:

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 32, 0, 32, -1, 1);
```

Comment: I used your code and it worked, it just that the points are too small, what is the proper glPointSize() I need to set?

Comment: @yarinCohen I thought the resolution of your window is 32x32? Let me quote your question: *"I have a 32x32 screen size"*

Comment: yes, it is, I'll add the init stuff to my post.

Comment: @yarinCohen If the screen has 32x32 pixel, the point size has to be 1.0 (default). Anyway  You cannot draw a fraction of a pixel. You either change the color of a pixel or you don't.

Comment: Ok, last question, is it possible to change the color for each pixel? atm I use glClearColor() to set all the points-colors

Comment: You have to set the color before `glVertex2f`. e.g. `glColor3f(i/32.0f, j/32.0f, 0.5f);` `glVertex2f(i,j);`